# Query Collection Table from Database

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I need to display records to the user from a view source. The user will then check a checkbox corresponding to the records they want to process, then click a button to submit the page. A custom process will loop through the selected records and process them.

To my surprise, this isn't an easy task in Apex. I've found in classic reports you can utilize APEX_APPLICATION.Gxxx arrays to accomplish it.

```
FOR i IN 1.. APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP 
    p_my_custom_dml(....);
END LOOP;
```

But there's no clean way to access the data corresponding to the row of the current checkbox. I would need to shove all my other columns into their own array then have a second loop that matches them up by primary key.

Interactive Grids have a "row selector" that at first sounds perfect. But the row selector doesn't "dirty" the records, so you're forced to write JS to loop over the selected rows and update some hidden field to dirty them.

The new method I'm exploring is using collections. I got the idea from [this](https://blogs.ontoorsolutions.com/post/how-to-query-apex-collection-data-in-database/) post. I'd like to build the collection in APEX, then loop through that same collection directly in my Oracle database. Since collections are session based, I would need to pass the session ID from APEX to my oracle procedure. Something like...

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE my_custom_proc ( p_session IN NUMBER DEFAULT wwv_flow.g_instance,
                                            p_app      IN VARCHAR DEFAULT apex_application.g_flow_id,
                                            p_ws_id    IN VARCHAR DEFAULT apex_workspaces.workspace_id)
IS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   apex_collections
    WHERE  collection_name = 'MY_COLLECTION';

BEGIN
  -- Set Workspace ID
  wwv_flow_api.Set_security_group_id (p_ws_id);
  -- Set Application ID
  apex_application.g_flow_id := p_app;
  -- Set Session ID
  apex_application.g_instance := p_session;

  --loop over collection records
  FOR RECORD IN c1
  LOOP
    --process records;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Then I would call this procedure from APEX like...

```
BEGIN
my_custom_proc(v('APP_SESSION'),
               v('APP_ID),
               apex_application_install.get_workspace_id);
END;
```

I like this approach because I don't have to deal with feeding the APEX row data into my procedure. I can just access it all directly on the database side. But the fact that I haven't seen this as a solution anywhere make me concerned.

My question - Are there any security or other issues with this method that I'm not seeing? I've read something that stated session ID's can't be trusted as these are able to change, but am not sure this is something I need to be concerned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page process doesn't need to worry about the session ID like you've stated above.

The blog post you linked was only relating to querying the collection view from SQL Developer. This is handy for debugging, but the cleaner way would be to use the APEX_SESSION package

```
begin
  apex_session.ATTACH (
     p_app_id     => 123
    ,p_page_id    => 1
    ,p_session_id => 12111327500847);
end;
/
```

You can add members to your collection using a similar manner to what I've described [here](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html), and just query the apex_collections table with the relevant collection_name in your page process.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Scott. In order to call apex_session.ATTACH with dynamic arguments from an Oracle database proc, would I have to pass the session/page/app_id into the procedure using the same method I used in my my_custom_proc (v('APP_SESSION'), etc..)

Comment: To be clear, the use of APEX_SESSION is for *debugging* purposes only in a *separate* session within a tool like SQL Developer. For your application, there is no need to explicitly reference your session ID when querying the APEX_COLLECTIONS view.